# Is there an eslint rule for avoiding negation within brackets?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is there an eslint rule for disallowing negation of an equality?

So, disallow:

```js
!(a === b)
```

and instead enforce:

```js
a !== b
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the `a !== b` enforcement is available but there is a `ESlint` rule called `no-unsafe-negation` that can be used to disallow the negation.

You might need to `customize` the enforcement by coming up with your own `ordering relation`

Reference link: [no-unsafe-negation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unsafe-negation)